# Texto TextView se ve cortado

Tags: android, android-studio, xml, textview

tengo un problema, estoy realizando una aplicación de notas con un cardview, linearLayout y un textView. El problema es que el texto se ve cortado como se ve en la imagen a continuación:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y aquí esta mi código de mi xml(Si es que tienen consejos para que este bien optimizado mi código o algo para arreglar otro problema que vean son bienvenidos):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:minWidth="156dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/note_card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="128dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:maxHeight="128dp"
        android:minHeight="128dp"
        app:contentPadding="5dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="156dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:minWidth="156dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/note_title"
                android:layout_width="156dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:text="Almuerzo mañana"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/note_content"
                android:layout_width="156dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:text="Ir a la tienda"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/note_time"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="Justo ahora"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Ojalá puedan ayudarme, gracias.

Comment: Los textos de la imagen  no son los mismos  en el xml, es ese el xml?

Comment: Si son esos, el note_title es el titulo de la nota que ves en la imagen que dice almuerzo mañana, en el xml se ve diferente porque la imagen la tome ya con valores rescatados de mi base de datos, ya edite mi código para que no existan confusiones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema se debe a que el `LinearLayout` que es el padre que contiene los `TextView` tiene una medida fija, y esto no permite que tengan un mayor tamaño:

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="156dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:minWidth="156dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
```

Usa `match_parent` para el ancho del contenedor:

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:minWidth="156dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
```

Comment: Muchas gracias acabo de solucionarlo con lo que me dijiste!!!

Comment: Excelente @Santiagozv , saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Lo ideal es intentar siempre dejar la mayoría de textos dentro de layouts no restringidos. En el enfoque clásico hay que usar mucho **wrap_content**, pero sería más interesante que estudiaras las bondades del nuevo **ConstraintLayout** , mucho más flexible y personalizable.

https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout

Se necesita un poco de práctica para dominar este moderno layout pero al final te permitirá obtener diseños muy flexibles que mostrarán todo justo como deseas en cualquier pantalla.

En cualquier caso, siempre es bueno meter un efecto ellipsize para truncar posibles textos largos mostrando puntos suspensivos en el caso de que no quepa todo. En tu caso observo que tienes puesta esta propiedad pero no te funciona porque cierto bug de android impide su uso correcto con maxLines>1 y tu tienes definido maxLines="2". De momento arréglalo borrando eso y añadiendo singleline="true":

<strike>android:maxLines="2"</strike>

android:singleLine="true"